# Running multiple activities in back in one tab

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am new to android and i am trying to implement the video call functionality in our android app .For this we need to provide the dailer screen at the receiver side.
I am able to provide the dailer screen at the receiver side .But the problem is that when ever the call ends it is **redirecting the dailer screen** it self .Actually it should be redirected to home page activity but it is not redirecting . Even if i made to  redirect to the home page activity it redirects to it.But in background still dailer activity is opening.

Overview: **Dailer activity--------> call connect activity--After call disconnects------->Expected to Redirect only home page activity** but in background dailer activity is also running actually it should not run(It should be displayed only when the incoming call is getting)

Comment: Please add your supporting code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Make sure that you have called finish(); when you move the user from dial to video call

2-  To move the user directly to the home you should call

```
startActivity(new Intent(VideoCallClass.this,Home.class));//ofcourse you should 
//replace the class names I included to ur class names
finish();
```

To control what happens for your app when you open it from recent apps you should track whole App Activity LifeCycle, so we will make a simple class for it and register it in the launcher activity :

```
public class AppController extends Application implements  
Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks  
{   
    @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

}

@Override
public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

}

@Override
public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

}

@Override
public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

}

@Override
public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

  }
}
```

The callback methods should be self-explanatory and do what we initially set out to do: They alert you when your application becomes awake or goes to sleep and you should implement your own logic. and to you use that class that we build before, u should call the following in the launcher Activity on OnCreate Below setContentView:

```
Application application = (Application)getApplicationContext();
application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new AppController());
```

Comment: Thank you for your response . I have already added that code in my android app but here i am again facing new issue that if my app is in recent apps and when i tap on the app icon it again by default redirects to the dailer  activity insted of redirecting to launcher activity.Can you please provide suggestions for this issue

Comment: so my suggestions solved ur first problem? so we can move to another

Comment: Yeah sure even i am also trying to fix that issue if you know please suggest how to  fix that issue to launch activity the actual declared activity as the launcher activity in the manifest file  when i opened from the recent tabs.

Comment: oh then if my answer  fixes ur first error , please accept  it as solution and upvote and I will write the fix for ur second issue now :)

Comment: By seeing your reply it self i have already voted for you but it is not displaying because i dont have more than 15 votes.

Comment: @sunikumar oh okay thanks! but there is a tick you can click it to accept as solution please

Comment: @sunikumar I posted the solution for your 2nd problem , but you should implement your logic very carefully

Comment: sure thank you i will  try to implement in my project